# Java RMI TCPEndpoint new socket timeout

Tags: java, tcp, rmi

I have an application with a simple client and server communicating through RMI.

I'm playing around to see how the client behaves when I kill the server.

The client gets stuck on creating a new socket. You can see the exception bellow:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:     172.17.2.100; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
                  at     sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
                  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
                  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
                  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
                  at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
                  ... 18 more.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
                  at   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                  ... 30 more.
```

At first I thought this had something to do with the sockets created by the RMIClientSocketFactory passed when creating the registry, but as you can see from the exception it's when the TCPEndpoint tries to create a new socket.

Since TCPEndpoint explicitly creates a new socket without using a timeout, I really don't see how to overcome this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to connect to a Registry at an IP adress you can't reach, or on a port that is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @EJP that's right. Like I said I killed the server. What I'm trying to figure out is how to avoid getting stuck for so long here. I've already tried some of sun's RMI properties (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) to no avail...

Comment: Just killing the server would cause 'connection refused', not a timeout. The timeout is cause ed by the network topology or a firewall. The stack trace is from a Registry lookup, not a call to your server, so killing the server JVM may have been even more irrelevant, if that's possible.

Comment: @EJP I should've been more explicit. Client and server are running on different machines, so I just "pulled the plug" on the server, which I think is a valid test. Yes, that is a lookup in this case (which I was testing in this case), but the same thing happens when performing a UnicastRef.invoke.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? You can set a connect timeout with those properties. It works.